# How to sync with local database data with online data when app is offline?

Tags: android, process

I want to build a mobile app where user can upload many tasks which will go to a server through API . after that All the uploaded tasks will be stored locally too. Then user can assign all the tasks from pending to done  offline(no internet). There will be a option where user can sync with all the done tasks which is stored locally to sync with the server to keep update with the pending and done tasks. How can i design this mobile app?

Comment: Check  [this](https://youtu.be/Mr8YKDh3li4) out

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an api to be triggered when your application comes back online.

For syncing you can either use a sync adapter approach which is now deprecated.

Or you can use the latest WorkManager api which provide you with all options like time , internet connection, battery etc  based runs and you focus would only be to write a job that runs calls this api.

Comment: can we make the whole process offline? can we make all the pending jobs to done in local db then give a button which only udtae the server if clciked?

Comment: Yes that is possible too then all you need is a foreground service in which you can write your code to hit your api and when user presses the button all data will be uploaded to the server in one go.